# static inner class in custom dialogfragment?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

If I were to define a dialogfragment like:

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements
DialogInterface.OnClickListener, DialogInterface.OnShowListener, 
DialogInterface.OnDismissListener {

private ProgressBar dialogProgressBar;
```

and have a custom `AsyncTask` as an inner class inside `MyDialogFragment` like:

```
public static class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
```

1. what is the best way for `MyAsyncTask` to access `dialogProgressBar`?  I could make `dialogProgressBar` `static` but that means all my dialogs share the same progressbar, which would not make sense
2. Again, since `MyAsyncTask` is `static`, how could I dismiss this dialog in `onPostExecute`?

The dialog starts the asynctask like this:

```
@Override public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
    myTask = new MyAsyncTask();
    myTask.execute();
}
```

I made `MyAsyncTask` a STATIC inner class because otherwise, if the dialog were dismissed, and thus destroyed, I won't leak `MyDialogFragment`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass your dialog as a parameter to the AsyncTask in the following way

```
public static class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<ProgressBar, Integer, Void> {
WeakReference<ProgressBar> progressBar;
protected Void doInBackground(ProgressBar...params){

   if(params!=null && params.length>0){

          progressBar = new WeakReference<ProgressBar>(params[0]);
   }
   ///do stuff
}

protected Void onPostExecute(Void result){

  ProgressBar p = progressBar.get();
   if(p!=null){
    p.dismiss();
   } 
}
}
```

way #2 - you can pass the ProgressBar as a parameter in the constructor of your class

```
     public MyAsyncTask(ProgressBar progressBar){
             //save the progressbar for use in the postexecute
       }
```